# SQL-Select Para calcular comissão de vendedor

Tags: sql

Preciso calcular o salário de um vendedor + 10% sobre cada atendimento que ele realizar.

[image: tabelas]

Pensei em fazer um select com um COUNT e depois fazer o cálculo. Porém não estou conseguindo.
Aqui está o que tentei, não retornou certo...

```
SELECT   count(a.codfunc),f.salario FROM funcionario f, atendimento a where f.salario=a.codfunc or a.codfunc='1' ;
```

Comment: A cada **atendimento** você deseja aumentar 10% do salário do funcionário?

Comment: Queira [edit] o post deixando mais claras as regras, preferencialmente com um exemplo do que deve acontecer, em especial sobre a regra dos 10%, conforme já perguntado pelo colega @Andre, para evitar que respostas se baseiem em interpretação equivocada. Adicionalmente, seria bom explicar a lógica da sua tentativa, para que fique mais fácil um detalhamento da parte específica que está com dificuldade em resolver.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Execute o seguinte `SELECT`:

```
SELECT funcionario.CODFUNC, 
           funcionario.NOME, 
           funcionario.SALARIO,
           funcionario.SALARIO * 0.1 * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM atendimento WHERE atendimento.CODFUNC = funcionario.CODFUNC) COMISSAO,
           funcionario.SALARIO + (funcionario.SALARIO * 0.1 * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM atendimento WHERE atendimento.CODFUNC = funcionario.CODFUNC)) SALARIO_TOTAL
  FROM funcionario
```

Onde serão recuperados os valores do `funcionario` juntamente com a `comissao`(*dada de acordo com a quantidade de atendimentos realizados por cada funcionario*) e o `salário total` resultante da soma do salário com a comissão de cada funcionário.

Caso queira realizar a *query* para um funcionário específico, basta adicionar a cláusula `WHERE` com o seu código no final da consulta acima, exemplo abaixo:

```
WHERE funcionario.cod = 1
```

Comment: *Downvoter* poderia explicar o motivo do -1 ou onde a resposta poderia ser melhorada?

Answer (score -2):

Bom dia,
está faltando a cláusula GROUP BY na consulta por isso está dando erro. Toda vez que se faz um agrupamento do tipo Count ou Sum deve-se usar um GROUP BY.

Veja como deve ficar.

```
SELECT   
count(a.codfunc),
f.salario 
FROM 
funcionario f, atendimento a 
where 
f.salario = a.codfunc 
or 
a.codfunc = '1' group by f.salario ;
```

Comment: Há dois funcionários cadastrado sendo que apenas um deles tem 5 atendimentos. Esse select trouxe os dois funcionários e como se os dois tivessem 5 atendimentos.

Answer (score -2):

Tente calcular com uma subquery a quantidade de atendimentos para cada funcionário.

```
SELECT funcionario.codfunc, 
       funcionario.nome, 
       (funcionario.salario * 0.1 * (SELECT count(*) FROM atendimento WHERE atendimento.codfunc = funcionario.codfunc)) AS comissao 
FROM funcionario;
```

Comment: Com esse select ele retorna os dois funcionários, em que parte eu deveria especificar o código do funcionário. Para retornar um por vez?

Comment: Com este SELECT ele retorna todos os funcionários existentes em sua tabela funcionario com o respectivo cálculo da comissão. Caso não queira todos os funcionários acrescente ao final uma cláususula WHERE especificando o(s) funcionário(s) desejado(s).